# Visibility property not working properly with fadeOut()

Tags: php, jquery, visibility, fadeout

I am developing a feedback page in a table with 3 columns.

```
Name         Feedback icons          status
-------------------------------------------------
Name1        icon1 icon2 icon3       Saved
Name2        icon1 icon2 icon3       Saved
-------------------------- and so on....
```

Initially the 3rd column is having css property `visibility:hidden`. On clicking any of the icon the 3rd column of that row need to show as 'Saved' and then disappear.
Its working for me on the first time, i.e. if I am clicking `icon2` on first time in the first row, saved will show and disappear, when I click `icon1` on the same row, it will not show the 3rd column.

When I click the next row, the 3rd column will come only on first click. Please help me.

**Html**

```
<table class="tbl_result">
   <tbody>
    <tr><td width="55%">Nahed </td>
       <td width="42%">
         <div id="tbl_row_icons0" class="tbl_row_icons">
          <div class="emoji_parent">
           <div class="emoji_2 emojichild">
            <a title="Poor" class="feedbck_name" href="#"><img src="/user_uploads/my.aisc.ac.cy/emoticon/poor.png"></a>
           </div>
         <!--second icon--!>
          <div class="emoji_3 emojichild"><a title="Good" class="feedbck_name" href="#"><img src="/user_uploads/my.aisc.ac.cy/emoticon/good.png"></a>
         </div>
       </div>
      </td><td width="7%" class="toggle_save">Saved</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

**CSS**

```
.toggle_save
{
    visibility:hidden;
    color:green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Jquery function**

```
//click event for icon 
$(".feedbck_name").click(function()
{    
   $(this)
       .closest('td')
       .next('td.toggle_save')
       .css('visibility','visible')
       .delay(1000)
       .fadeOut();

   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are doing fadeOut() your script will make it display:none in css property.
You need to fade on visibility instead.
Try below code for the same

```
$(".feedbck_name").click(function()
{    
   $(this).parent('td').siblings('td.toggle_save')
    .css('opacity','1')
    .css("visibility", "visible")
    .fadeTo(1500, 0, function(){
         $(this).parent('td').siblings('td.toggle_save')
         .css("visibility", "hidden").css('opacity','1');   
    });
    return false;
});
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qwdjh61/2/) for the same

Comment: Its working on clicking each icon on first time.when we click the same icon,its not working..especially after clicking the icon immediately clicking another icon

Comment: This will not display the text on fast clicking between icons.Please help me

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9qwdjh61/5/ Go here this will help. Check .stop(true,true) in snippet

Comment: Thanks bro..it worked.Can you just give any logic of this stop function() used here

Comment: Generally when you do animations let say, fadeTo,fadeOut,fadeIn, It all has time set. If you don't set default time is settled but, time factor is always there. now stop() function makes sure that we clear the queue and animation which is ongoing, so, first true is to clear all animations that are ongoing on object and second true is to jump immediately to the end. When you will open console and check your code after removing stop, you will find that opacity factor will be going gradually from 1 to 0 not in jump that is why it looks like fade. now our stop will remove all ongoing tasks as such